# rspec: expect method call on instance of EXACT class (not subclasses)

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have code which calls two slightly different things.  One which instantiates Foo explicitly, and another which uses a gem which instantiates Foo internally (i.e. not my code).

I am trying to `expect_any_instance_of(Foo).not_to receive(:bar)`, but the calls from the gem are triggering this expectation, causing it to fail (an instance of `class SubFoo < Foo` is receiving `bar`).

How can I write this expectation for only the exact `Foo` class, and not any subclasses of Foo?

Answer (score 1):

You could prepare the `Foo` instance which exactly would supposed not to receive `:bar`.

```
let(:foo) { Foo.create() }
```

Then pass it to the method you're trying to test or to the action as request params etc (depends on what you're testing and how).

And then you'll be able to use

```
expect(foo).not_to receive :bar
```

It's not what you **exactly** want. But I believe it could help you in your use case.